# Using the Windows Store with an Active Directory account

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-store

Is there a way to still use apps in the app store without having to switch from an AD account to a Windows Live account?

I find it very annoying that I have to switch from my current account to a Windows Live account just to use apps.